# What is the benefit of import in a namespace in R?

Tags: r, namespaces, package

The namespace mechanism of R allows one to `export` functions which then are visible to the user. Furthermore, it allows to `import` functions from other packages. Whereas the benefit of export is obvious, I have more problems understanding the benefit of import.

One benefit seems to be, that one can use functions from other packages without attaching the package and thereby saving memory. This is exemplified in section [1.6.4 in the writing R extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#An-example).

However, there must be other benefits of the import function. Especially, [section 1.6.6 (that deals with S4 classes)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Name-spaces-with-S4-classes-and-methods) shows the `namespace` of the stats4 package:

```
 export(mle)
 importFrom("graphics", plot)
 importFrom("stats", optim, qchisq)
 ## For these, we define methods or (AIC, BIC, nobs) an implicit generic:
 importFrom("stats", AIC, BIC, coef, confint, logLik, nobs, profile,
            update, vcov)
 exportClasses(mle, profile.mle, summary.mle)
 ## All methods for imported generics:
 exportMethods(coef, confint, logLik, plot, profile, summary, show, update, vcov)
 ## implicit generics which do not have any methods here
 export(AIC, BIC, nobs)
```

Here there are functions imported which are neither S4 classes nor generics (where it would make sense to use import as well, as documented in the example in [that section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Name-spaces-with-S4-classes-and-methods)), but functions like `plot` from the `graphics` package which are automatically loaded when R starts.

Therefore my question is, what is the benefit of importing functions like `plot`, `optim` or `qchisq`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If a function `foo` is imported from package Bar then it is found regardless of what the user does to their search path, e.g., by attaching a package Baz that also has a function `foo`. Without a name space, the package code would suddenly find itself using `Baz::foo`. There are also efficiency issues (`foo` is found immediately, rather than after searching through all symbols on the search path), but these are likely to be trivial for most applications. In the same way, `importFrom` is an improvement over `import` because of fewer collisions (or use of unintended functions) and more efficient look-up.

With S4 (and S3) things can get quite complicated. A non-generic function like `graphics::plot` can be promoted to a generic (with `setGeneric`) in two different packages, and each generic can have its own set of methods attached. A package author will want to be precise about which `plot` generic, and hence which methods dispatch table, their classes and methods see.

Calling a function with `pkg::foo` always resolves to the intended function. It requires that pkg be listed in the Depends: field of the DESCRIPTION file (maybe in Imports: but then it seems like misleading advertising to not import from pkg), polluting the user's search path. It also involves two symbol look-ups and a function call (`::`), and so is less efficient. The lazy and lack-of-attention-to-detail part of me also sees use of `::` as tedious and error prone.

The package [codetoolsBioC](https://hedgehog.fhcrc.org/bioconductor/trunk/madman/Rpacks/codetoolsBioC) (via svn with username and password `readonly`) can generate a NAMESPACE file from an existing package (or at least it could before recent changes to R-devel introduced a NAMESPACE on packages without one; I haven't tried codetoolsBioC on such a package).

Comment: That means, importing such a function does only make sense if one wants to promote it to a generic? (If one wants to assume that there are no other functions in the search path called `plot`)

Comment: It always makes sense to import a function (from a package other than base, which is always available) that your package uses, otherwise when some 3rd package defines a function `plot = function (...) "I have a good story to tell"` your code breaks. You don't have control over the search path, the user does.

Comment: If however I always call a function using the `::` operator (e.g., always `graphics::plot()` instead of `plot()`) is there still a benefit of import if a package is already attached?

Comment: @Martin Morgan: I am not sure to get everything. I have posted another question linked to that. Can you have a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501906/define-a-function-in-a-specific-namespace

Comment: @Henrik Using the :: operator doesn't always work, as in the case of raster::plot. Also, if the package is already attached, it may be unnecessarily verbose, though it is generally good for portability to be specific about function namespaces.