# define a function in a specific namespace

Tags: r, namespaces

I have created a package 'mypackage' (with a namespace 'mypackage' attached)
In this package there is a function that I can call either with

```
'myfunction'
```

or

```
'mypackage::myfunction'
```

Now I want to replace myfunction by another version (updated).

I used to do

```
source(path)
```

where path is the path of a file where the updated 'myfunction' is defined

Now I moved to R 2.14.x and this system doesnt work because apparently R checks first if there is a function inside the same namespace, and if there is one, it uses this one and not the others.

My question: how can I push the updated function to be in the same namespace as the package one?

Answer (score 9):

See `?assignInNamespace`. For example

```
assignInNamespace("myfunction", foo, "mypackage")
```

will assign the object `foo` to the object named `"myfunction"` in namespace `"mypackage"`. `foo` can be whatever object you want, even `myfunction` but you will need to be careful to ensure you call `mypackage::myfunction` if you also have `myfunction` in the global environment/workspace.