# How to handle dependencies (`Depends:`) of imported packages (`Imports:`)

Tags: r, import, dependencies, package

I'm trying to use `Imports:` instead of `Depends:` in the `DESCRIPTION` files of my packages, yet I still feel I've got some more to understand on this ;-)

What I learned from [this post](http://obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/) (by the way: awesome post!!!) is that everything my package, say `mypkg`, imports (say `imported.pkg`) via `Imports:` lives in environment `imports:mypkg` instead of being attached to the search path. When trying to find `foo` that ships with `imported.pkg`, R looks in `imports:mypkg` before traversing the search list. So far, so good.

### Actual question

If `imported.pkg` (imported by `mypkg`) **depends** on a certain other package (stated in `Depends:` section of the package's `DESCRIPTION` file), do I need to make this very package a `Depends:` dependency of my package in order for R to find functions of that package? So it seems to me at the moment as otherwise R complains.

### Evidence

Seems like simply **importing** such a package is not enough. As an example, take package `roxygen2` ([CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html)). It depends on `digest` while importing a bunch of other packages. I imported it (along with `digest` as `mypkg` also needs it) and checked environment `imports:mypkg` which does list the `digest` function: `"digest" %in% parent.env(asNamespace("mypkg"))` returns `TRUE`

Yet when running `roxygenize()` from **within** a function that is part of `mypkg`, R complains that it can't find `digest`.

Comment: You also need to declare an `importFrom` in the `NAMESPACE` file. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283134/what-is-the-benefit-of-import-in-a-namespace-in-r or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13261139/602276

Comment: I carried out the actual import via `import(imported.pkg)` and `import(digest)` in my `NAMESPACE` file (entire packages), that should do as well, shouldn't it? If something failed, there would also be no `digest` in the `imports:mypkg` environment - which there is.

Comment: I think this falls under the "caveat" section of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8638902/967840

Comment: Ahhh, okay! Thanks for the pointer! One more question though: when my functions call functions in packages that my package **imports**, do I need to do anything special to tell R "hey, look in the `imports:mypkg` environment first before going to the search path" (e.g. by using `::`) or does R figure that out itself?

Comment: In that respect: can't I tell R **explicitly** to look in `imports:mypkg` first, "no matter what" in the sense of "also when calling a package's function that relies on packages that have not been declared as *imports* in the package's `NAMESPACE` files"? Because `mypkg` would take care of importing the dependency, so its functions would actually be available in `imports:mypkg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at my blog : http://r2d2.quartzbio.com/posts/package-depends-dirty-hack-solution.html
Now i have a better and cleaner solution but not published yet. 
Hope it helps.