# import vs importFrom in NAMESPACE file

Tags: r, namespaces, cran

The section on NAMESPACE files from the [Writing R extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) manual says:

> Using *importFrom* selectively rather than *import* is good practice.

Why is this true? Is this just to protect yourself from masking and naming conflicts when importing multiple packages, or is there a performance difference?

Comment: [Maybe useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283134/what-is-the-benefit-of-import-in-a-namespace-in-r), if not a duplicate.

Comment: I had to write a package for a class, so I know firsthand that selectively using `importFrom` rather than `import` prevents you from inadvertently grabbing things that you didn't want to and leading to conflicts. I recall introducing a bug because a function I named was the same as a function that I `import`ed. I can't imagine that there is notable performance difference.